# CSS calc mixed use of height and width

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a `div` element (with a background image) that I want to occupy the smaller of 40% of the parent element's width or 100% of parent element's height.

Is this possible with CSS `calc()` or do I need to use javascript?

Comment: You mean you want the size of the background image to either be 40% of the parent element's width or 100% of the height, based on which one is smaller?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but take a look at [`min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min).

Comment: @code yes something like that.  is there a way to do it like calc(min(40% * width, 100% * height)) ?